# Downloading files in parallel using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing function that is downloading a bunch of files. However, about 1 in 20 errors with the following:

```
ContentTooShortError: retrieval incomplete
```

The function that I am using to download files is:

```
def getter(url, dest):
    video_files.append(urllib.urlretrieve(url, dest)[0])
```

Why is this error occurring, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If it is possible, you should probably use requests instead of urllib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.error.html) states, this happens when the server (gracefully) closes the connection without sending you the whole HTTP body, as specified by `Content-Length` - it's a **server error**.

You can try to "fix it" simply by retrying later.

Since you're grabbing many videos at once, it's possible that there's some mechanism at the server to detect and throttle such actions. Try to rate-limit your requests and see if the problem persists